# iOS Dismissing a popover that is in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios

I've been learning a lot about popovers and found out how to get them to dismiss gracefully using delegates. The issue I have now is that there is a popup in my program that is controlled with a `UINavigationController`.

When the user presses a button on my parent `ViewController`, the popover comes up as it should and the user can navigate through 3 scenes using tables. Everything works fine until it comes time to dismiss the pop over.

On the final scene I would like to dismiss the popover whenever the user presses an index. If I didn't have the `UINavigationController` attached to these views it would be easy. I don't know how to implement the delegate.

I tried making a delegate in my `UINavigationController` implementation, but XCode tells me that `UINavigationController` already has a delegate. Is there some way to use the delegate that is already there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should post the code where you dismiss the popover.

Comment: I would love to, but I do not know how to dismiss the popover with a UINavigationController.

Comment: How are you setting up your interface? Storyboard? Code? What do you mean by "popup that is controlled with a UINavigationController"? Do you mean the content view controller of the popover is a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think using a notification might be better in this case, since your controller from which you want to start the dismissal is far removed from the popover controller which should do the dismissal (so it would be hard to set the delegate). If you're using a popover segue in a storyboard, you can get a reference to the popover controller from the segue object. From the controller which initiates the popover segue, I put this code:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UIPopoverController *pop;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissPopover) name:@"DismissPopoverNotification" object:nil];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    pop = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
}

-(void)dismissPopover {
    [pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

And in the last controller, where choosing a row in a table causes the popover to be dismissed, you could have this code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DismissPopoverNotification" object:self];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly. I definitely need to read up on Notification Center. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a follow-up question for using Notification Center this way. Why would you ever use a view delegate over notification center? This seems a lot easier. By view delegate I mean creating a protocol method in the popover view and having the parent view controller call the delegate to dismiss it.

Comment: Delegates are definitely preferred if you have multiple methods in a protocol. When there's only one method, it would seem like a toss up to me. Apple seems to prefer using delegates, especially for the case where you sending data back to a controller that created you -- in that case it's easy to set the delegate to self.

Answer (score 0):

I use notifications quite a bit to relay data back and forth. This additional line, I was unaware of...

pop = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];

Yet, I do want to point out one tiny detail that was missed...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissPopover:) name:@"DismissPopoverNotification" object:nil];
```

There should be a colon after dismissPopover... see above. Without it, the compiler was crashing.

Other than that... I want to say thanks for this! It helped with one dismissal issue, and I'm going to try it on another.